# In Perl, how to create a "mixed-encoding" string (or a raw sequence of bytes) in a scalar?

Tags: perl, utf-8, scalar, bytestream

In a Perl script of mine, I have to write a mix of UTf-8 and raw bytes into files.

I have a big string in which everything is encoded as UTF-8. In that "source" string, UTF-8 characters are just like they should be (that is, UTF-8-valid byte sequences), while the "raw bytes" have been stored as if they were codepoints of the value held by the raw byte. So, in the source string, a "raw" byte of 0x50 would be stored as one 0x50 byte; whereas a "raw" byte of 0xff would be stored as a 0xc3 0xbf two-byte utf-8-valid sequence. When I write these "raw" bytes back, I need to put them back to single-byte form.

I have other data structures allowing me to know which parts of the string represent what kind of data. A list of fields, types, lengths, etc.

When writing in a plain file, I write each field in turn, either directly (if it's UTF-8) or by encoding its value to ISO-8859-1 if it's meant to be raw bytes. It works perfectly.

Now, in some cases, I need to write the value not *directly* to a file, but as a record of a BerkeleyDB (Btree, but that's mostly irrelevant) database.
To do that, I need to write ALL the values that compose my record, in a single write operation. Which means that I need to have a scalar that holds a mix of UTF-8 and raw bytes.

---

Example:

Input Scalar (all hex values): 61 C3 8B 00 C3 BF

Expected Output Format: 2 UTF-8 characters, then 2 raw bytes.

Expected Output: 61 C3 8B 00 FF

---

At first, I created a string by concatenating the same values I was writing to my file from an empty string. And I tried writing that very string to a "standard" file without adding encoding. I got '?' characters instead of all my raw bytes over 0x7f (because, obviously, Perl decided to consider my string to be UTF-8).

---

Then, to try and tell Perl that it was already encoded, and to "please not try to be smart about it", I tried to encode the UTF-8 parts into "UTF-8", encode the binary parts into "ISO-8859-1", and concatenate everything. Then I wrote it. This time, the bytes looked perfect, but the parts which were already UTF-8 had been "double-encoded", that is, each byte of a multi-byte character had been seen as its codepoint...

---

I thought Perl wasn't supposed to re-encode "internal" UTF-8 into "encoded" UTF-8, if it was internally marked as UTF-8. The string holding all the values in UTF-8 comes from a C API, which sets the UTF-8 marker (or is supposed to, at the very least), to let Perl know it is *already* decoded.

Any idea about what I did miss there?

Is there a way to tell Perl what I want to do is just put a bunch of bytes one after another, and to please not try to interpret them in any way?  The file I write to is opened as ">:raw" for that very reason, but I guess I need a way to specify that a given scalar is "raw" too?

---

---

Epilogue: I found the cause of the problem. The $bigInputString was *supposed* to be entirely composed of UTF-8 encoded data. But it *did* contain raw bytes with big values, because of a bug in C (turns out a "char" (not "unsigned char") is best tested with bitwise operators, instead of a " > 127"... ahem). So, "big" bytes weren't split into a two-bytes UTF-8 sequence, in the C API.

Which means the $bigInputString, created from the bad C data, didn't have the expected contents, and Perl rightfully didn't like it either.

After I corrected the bug, the string correctly encoded to UTF-8 (for the parts I wanted to keep as UTF-8) or LATIN-1 (for the "raw bytes" I wanted to convert back), and I got no further problems.

Sorry for wasting your time, guys. But I still learned some things, so I'll keep this here. Moral of the story, Devel::Peek is GOOD for debugging (thanks ikegami), and one should always double check, instead of assuming. Granted, I was in a hurry on friday, but the fault is still mine.

So, thanks to everyone who helped, or tried to, and special thanks to ikegami (again), who used quite a bit of his time helping me.

Comment: Can you update your post with examples of the strings?

Comment: Specifically, provide representative inputs and what outputs you want for those inputs.

Comment: I updated for clarity, as written. I'll update with examples.

Comment: Re "*Expected Output Format*", How do you know which to convert and which not to convert?

Comment: As stated in the question, I have *other* data structures which let me know what the source string represents

Comment: Re "*turns out a "char" (not "unsigned char") is best tested with bitwise operators, instead of a " > 127"... ahem).*" `char` can be signed or unsigned depending on platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have

```perl
my $in = "\x61\xC3\x8B\x00\xC3\xBF";
```

and you want

```perl
my $out = "\x61\xC3\x8B\x00\xFF";
```

This is the result of decoding only some parts of the input string, so you want something like the following:

```perl
sub decode_utf8 { my ($s) = @_; utf8::decode($s) or die("Invalid Input"); $s }

my $out = join "",
               substr($in, 0, 3),
   decode_utf8(substr($in, 3, 1)),
   decode_utf8(substr($in, 4, 2));
```

[Tested](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/4fb280e170b1786a3f128821f173f52e).

Alternatively, you could decode the entire thing and re-encode the parts that should be encoded.

```perl
sub encode_utf8 { my ($s) = @_; utf8::encode($s); $s }

utf8::decode($in) or die("Invalid Input");
my $out = join "",
   encode_utf8(substr($in, 0, 2)),
               substr($in, 2, 1),
               substr($in, 3, 1);
```

[Tested](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/905c16f2e017fb8c9db2166264f5969d).

You have not indicate how you know which to decode and which not to decode, but you indicated you have this information.

Comment: I have a loop, iterating on an array containing references to hashes. Each referenced hash represents a field of the record. The hashes have keys like "length" (with associated value being the number of *elements*, either *characters* if UTF-8, or *raw bytes* (that need to be converted back from UTF-8) if binary, "type" ('U' for UTF-8, 'B' for binary), and the like. The format of that data structure is irrelevant to the question. I KNOW what I'm reading, and what I need to convert it to. What I do not know is how to prevent Perl from messing with the data when I put it all in a single string.

Comment: I was using the . operator, to concatenate the strings. Maybe the join function will do what I'm expecting.


Office is now closed, I'll try this on monday. Thanks.

Comment: `.` works just as well as `join`

Comment: Then it won't work. As I said, my first attempt to store those was by concatenating. However, Perl saw that I was concatenating those non-UTF-8 values to a nice UTF-8 chain, and decided to replace all the utf-8-invalid values (like the FF in the example) with '?' characters. Thus altering the data.

Comment: Re "*Then it won't work. *", Then you haven't explained the problem adequately. Is `$in` incorrect or is `$out` incorrect?

Comment: Re "*What I do not know is how to prevent Perl from messing with the data when I put it all in a single string.*",  Concatenation doesn't mess anything up. If you have character a, b, c in one string and x, y, z in the other, you will end with a string with characters a, b,c, x, y, z.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried explaining in the question. The problem is Perl sees that as a UTF-8 string, and the "raw" bytes as INVALID UTF-8. While I merely want a BYTE STRING.

Comment: None one of that makes any sense whatever. Character just means "string element", and it's a number. As long as each of the numbers is in 0x00..0xFF (which they are in both `$in` and `$out``), print those strings to a raw will result in bytes with those values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237219/discussion-between-kzwix-and-ikegami).

Comment: Found the problem, your suggestions (especially about Devel::Peek) helped solve it. I edited the question to show the cause.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a Unicode string where you know what each codepoint is supposed to be stored as - a UTF-8 sequence or a single byte, and a way to create a template string where each character represents what the corresponding one of the unicode string is supposed to use (`U` for UTF-8, `C` for single byte to keep things simple), you can use `pack`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub process {
    my ($str, $formats) = @_;
    my $template = "C0$formats";
    my @chars = map { ord } split(//, $str);
    pack $template, @chars;
}

my $str = "\x61\xC3\x8B\x00\xC3\xBF";
utf8::decode($str);
print process($str, "UUCC"); # Outputs 0x61 0xc3 0x8b 0x00 0xff
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the tip.

I'll have to wait for Monday to test the different answers given, but it seems promising.

Comment: Well, it was due to a bug (cf. edit), but thanks anyway.